# Dynamically adding views to CardView without duplicating

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a layout for `CardView` with 2 TextViews and 2 Buttons initially. Based on the #options in `poll.getOptions()`, a `Cardview` can have up to 5 buttons. So I want to add dynamically those buttons... If I add them in `onBindViewHolder`, after clicking a button, it adds duplicates of these buttons. I tried to add it in `onCreateViewHolder` but when I try to create a new button it gives me a `NullPointerException`. I tried in many ways but can't find solution. What is the true way of adding dynamic views in `cardview` or why it gives me that error?

**Layout for `CardView`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <data>
            <variable
                name = "poll"
                type = "mattoncino.pollo.Poll" />
        </data>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
            card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/listItemLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:text="@{poll.name}"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/questionTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="@{poll.question}"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/opt1Button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:text="@{poll.getText(1)}"
                    android:enabled="@{!poll.disabled}"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/opt2Button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:text="@{poll.getText(2)}"
                    android:enabled="@{!poll.disabled}"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </layout>
```

**My `CardViewAdapter` class:**

```
public class PollsCardViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PollsCardViewAdapter.CardViewHolder> {

        private List<Poll> activePolls;
        private final static String TAG = "CARDVIEW_ADAPTER";


        public PollsCardViewAdapter(List<Poll> polls){
            activePolls = polls;
        }

        public static class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private ActivePollsListItemBinding listItemBinding;

            public CardViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);
                listItemBinding = DataBindingUtil.bind(v);
            }


            public ActivePollsListItemBinding getBinding(){
                return listItemBinding;
            }
        }


        // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public PollsCardViewAdapter.CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.active_polls_list_item, parent, false);

            CardViewHolder holder = new CardViewHolder(v);
            Context context = holder.getBinding().nameTextView.getContext();

            Poll poll = activePolls.get(viewType);

            for (int i = 2; i < poll.getOptions().size(); i++) {
                int opt = i + 1;
                Button button = createNewOptionButton(context, poll.getText(opt));
                if(poll.isDisabled()) {
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else button.setText(poll.getText(opt));
                parent.addView(button);
            }

            return holder;
        }


        // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final PollsCardViewAdapter.CardViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            final Poll poll = activePolls.get(position);
            final LinearLayout rLayout = holder.getBinding().listItemLayout;

            if(!poll.isDisabled()){
                for (int i = 2; i < rLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
                    final View view = rLayout.getChildAt(i);
                    final int opt = i - 1;

                    if(view instanceof Button){
                        final Button button = (Button) view;
                        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                button.setText(button.getText().toString() + "    " + "\u2713");
                             setCardDetails(holder.getBinding().nameTextView.getContext(), rLayout, poll, opt);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            holder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.poll, poll);
            holder.getBinding().executePendingBindings();
        }

        private void setCardDetails(final Context context, final LinearLayout rLayout, final Poll poll, final int opt){
            poll.setDisabled(true);
            disableOptionButtons(rLayout);
            rLayout.addView(addMessageView(context));

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            final Runnable r = new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    poll.addVote(opt);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            };
            handler.post(r);
        }


        private void disableOptionButtons(ViewGroup layout){
            for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
                if(child.hasOnClickListeners())
                    child.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        private TextView addMessageView(Context context){
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            TextView textView = new TextView(context);
            textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            textView.setId(View.generateViewId());
            textView.setText("Thanks for voting! Wait for results...");
            textView.setTextSize(20);
            textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);

            return textView;
        }

        private static Button createNewOptionButton(Context context, String option) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            final Button button = new Button(context);
            button.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            button.setId(View.generateViewId());
            button.setTextSize(18);
            button.setText(option);
            //button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            return button;

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return activePolls.size();
        }
    }
```

**The exception that I get, inside the `createNewOptionButton()`**

```
mattoncino.pollo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: mattoncino.pollo, PID: 4684
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams.getViewLayoutPosition(RecyclerView.java:10862)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.getPosition(RecyclerView.java:7949)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.updateLayoutState(LinearLayoutManager.java:1184)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1323)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fixLayoutEndGap(LinearLayoutManager.java:894)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:636)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3844)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1160)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2317)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2023)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the safest bet would be to add all 5 buttons in the layout xml, and have them with

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

so they don't appear.

Then in `onBindViewHolder` you can check the number of buttons needed, and modify the visibility accordingly, using [`View.setVisibility()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int))

Sample code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PollsCardViewAdapter.CardViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ...

    int numOfButtons = poll.getOptions().size();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Button b = holder.buttons[i];
        if (i < numOfButtons) {
            b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // configure button's text and whatever
        } else {
            b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: it's possibly a solution, but i would like to understand how it can be done without creating them before. Bcs there can be cases where you don't know Views to add primarily.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the buttons dynamically.

Set the poll option with the onclicklistener and inside the onclicklistener's onclick method..

Create 5 new Buttons and add it to the cardView .

```
Button btn1 = new Button(context);
BUtton btn2 = new Button(context);
Button btn3 = new Button(context);

cardView.addView (btn1);
```

Repeat this.

To get the cardView of particular item ..

define the onclicklistener in the viewHolder and to get the position use the getAdapterPosition() method.

By this way you can add it

Comment: i think you misunderstood the problem. Dynamic options are not added by clicking the button. Clicking the button should just disable buttons to prevent a second click. But buttons should be created at the beginning. But doint it in onBindViewHolder causes to readd same options again and again when you click a button or scroll down.

Comment: okay then try doing the same in the onbindviewholder but add all the buttons to a RelativeLayout or some layout and then add that layout to the cardview. Before you do this if that relativeLayout is present remove that layout by calling removeChildAt() and then re-add all buttons.